# Excel Formula to Display multiple values (like Vlookup)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to perform something similar to a vlookup, but with one value I'd like to display the multiple items it discovers on a different sheet.  Ex. Lookup A,  A found, with information in column B that is unique, then Finds A again from a different line in the second worksheet, with information in column B that is again unique.

Comment: I have achieved this in a similar context using `IF` and array formulas. To provide further assistance can you please provide sample data and desired output? Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The multi-return is a pretty common question.  The main idea is to use `INDEX-SMALL` instead of `INDEX-MATCH`.  Normally you just search for the row to return using `MATCH`.  In this case, you need to track multiple matches and return them in order.  The "in order" part is best handled by `SMALL`, feeding it an input from `ROW` to get an array of increasing numbers.

**Picture of ranges**

[image: ranges for formula]

**Formula** in cell `F3` is an array formula (entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) and copied down to ensure it covers as many matches as could occur.  The extra rows return `#NUM!` when not needed.

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$8,SMALL(IF($B$3:$B$8=$E$3,ROW($B$3:$B$8)-ROW($B$2)),ROW(1:1)))
```

**How it works**.

- Outside call is to `INDEX` which is looking at the `VALUE` column and returning a result from there.
- `INDEX` needs a row number to return the value.  This row number is determined by finding which rows match the given search term.
- In order to find the rows, the `ID` column is compared to the search value in `E3`.  That check is wrapped in an `IF` which returns the `ROW` number if there is a match.
- The row number is calculated as `ROW()-ROW(top)` this is to account for the offset of my data starting in `B3`.
- Once we have an array of row numbers, `SMALL` is used to return them in increasing order.  `SMALL` will skip non numbers which includes the `FALSE` values returned for non-matching rows.
- Finally, in order to a single number for `INDEX`, `SMALL` uses `ROW(1:1)` which will increment as the formula is copied down, giving 1-2-3-...